# Extjs controller define inside navigation

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new Extjs user I defined controller inside navigation but not working. Please help.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Navigation', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    alias: 'widget.navigationController',

    views: ['Navigation'],


    refs : [{
        ref: 'navigationView',
        selector: 'navigation'
    }],


    init: function(application){
        console.log('controller init');
        this.control({
            'navigation': {
                'golocale': this.goLocale,
                'gobrand': this.goBrand,
                'gosize': this.goSize,
                'goarticle': this.goArticle,
                'gogender': this.goGender,
                'goprofile': this.goProfile,
                scope: this
            }
        });
    },


    goLocale: function(link){
        console.log('locale clicked');
        console.dir(link);
    },


    goBrand: function(link){
        console.log('brand clicked');
        // Also tried:
        // var viewport = this.getView('Viewport').create();
        var viewport = link.up('viewport');
        console.dir(viewport);
    },
```

console error bellow

```
 MyApp.controller.Navigation.addListener(): The specified callback function is undefined
```

Comment: Where are the other methods? `goSize`, `goArticle` etc? That's likely why it's throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing to your function "control" an object.

Inside that object, `this` points to the object, not to the controller anymore. Please try

```
init: function(application){
    console.log('controller init');
    var me = this; // "me" is scope to controller
    this.control({
        'navigation': {
            'golocale': me.goLocale,
            'gobrand': me.goBrand,
            'gosize': me.goSize,
            'goarticle': me.goArticle,
            'gogender': me.goGender,
            'goprofile': me.goProfile,
            scope: me
        }
    });
```